# BeagleBone Black and java revalidate()

Tags: java, linux, beagleboneblack

I am running Linux Angstrom on BeagleBone Black and with this Oracle JDK "Linux ARM v6/v7 VFP Soft Float ABI". I wrote a simple code to have a panel inside a frame with 1 button and that is running just fine. However, when I adding some drawings (lines and circles) to the panel and refresh with any validate() or revalidate(), I get the following error when I try to run the jar file.

java: res_quer.c:251 __libc_res_nquery: Assertion 'hp != hp2' failed. Aborted

Any idea about how to solve that issue, if not, any idea about how to refresh the panel so that it displays the updated content without using validate or revalidate?
(I called repaint explicit but it did nothing)

Any ideas, recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the OS itself, the same issue has been facing users on Fedora systems  in some setups. There is a batch for fixing the issue in Fedora, however I didn't try it on Angstrom. Instead I just installed Debian on my BeagleBone and the JAR file is working like charm now.